# In artillery can I run multiple scenarios simultaneously

Tags: performance, automated-tests, load-testing, web-api-testing, artillery

I need to run load test on 5 different APIs with different loads, simultaneously.
Right now I have 5 yaml files for load tests of the 5 APIs. I am looking for a way to either run all 5 yaml files in parallel or somehow run tests on APIs together at one time.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar question and came across this - https://github.com/artilleryio/artillery/discussions/2288.

> You can typically orchestrate that at the level of your CI (Jenkins/GH Actions/other), with either a custom script, or multiple jobs. For example, in a previous company, we had a custom generic Jenkins job that was capable of running any of the load tests in the repo. Then, we would have orchestrator jobs that could run multiple of those (either in parallel or sequentially), for different reasons.

We are experimenting with Github Action and AWS Codebuild and will post an update in a couple of weeks.